# Daily Log Files from Single Log File

Tags: logs, split

I want to split my user.log file which is always in open mode as logs are written every time. I want to split it into daily log files i.e. userlogs_29072018 and the main user.log file should have data up till one month. Older than that should be mantained in seperate daily log files.

Sample Logs are shown below:

```
May 11 21:23:57 iibapp1 user:info IIB[3539342]: IBM Integration Bus v9007 (PTCLBK01.RectificationClaimService) [Thread 8740] (Msg 1/1) BI
P2153I: About to 'Start' an execution group.
May 11 21:24:01 iibapp1 user:info IIB[3539342]: IBM Integration Bus v9007 (PTCLBK01.RectificationClaimService) [Thread 8740] (Msg 1/1) BI
P3132I: The HTTP Listener has started listening on port '7860' for 'http' connections.
May 11 21:24:01 iibapp1 user:info IIB[3539342]: IBM Integration Bus v9007 (PTCLBK01.RectificationClaimService) [Thread 8740] (Msg 1/1) BI
P2154I: Execution group finished with Configuration message.
May 11 21:24:44 iibapp1 user:info IIB[7209156]: IBM Integration Bus v9007 (PTCLBK01.ProvisionComptelService) [Thread 1] (Msg 1/1) BIP2208
I: Execution group (64) started: process '7209156'; thread '1'; additional information: brokerName 'PTCLBK01' (operation mode 'advanced')
; executionGroupUUID '581fc422-5301-0000-0080-8f9b8378eb10'; executionGroupLabel 'ProvisionComptelService'; queueManagerName 'PTCLQM01';
trusted 'false'; userId 'mbrkrs'; migrationNeeded 'false'; brokerUUID 'c144e7ae-d59c-11e5-af0a-0afea9560000'; filePath '/opt/IBM/mqsi/9.0
.0.7'; workPath '/MQHA/DBK01/mqsi'; ICU Converter Path ''; ordinality '59'.


May 12 00:57:36 iibapp1 user:err|error IIB[6095148]: IBM Integration Bus v9007 (PTCLBK01.ProvisionComptelService2New) [Thread 14140] (Msg
 2/6) BIP2230E: Error detected whilst processing a message in node 'com.ibm.pk.ptcl.esb.ComptelProv.Comptel_IL_Request_flow.modify_Instan
tLinkWebServices.Request'.
May 12 00:57:36 iibapp1 user:err|error IIB[6095148]: IBM Integration Bus v9007 (PTCLBK01.ProvisionComptelService2New) [Thread 14140] (Msg
 3/6) BIP3754E: The SOAP Request Node or SOAP Async Request Node com.ibm.pk.ptcl.esb.ComptelProv.Comptel_IL_Request_flow.modify_InstantLi
nkWebServices.Request encountered an error while processing the outbound SOAP request.
May 12 00:57:36 iibapp1 user:err|error IIB[6095148]: IBM Integration Bus v9007 (PTCLBK01.ProvisionComptelService2New) [Thread 14140] (Msg
 4/6) BIP3162S: An HTTP error occurred. The HTTP Request-Line was: 'POST /ilws/InstantLinkSOA HTTP/1.1^M '.
May 12 00:57:36 iibapp1 user:err|error IIB[6095148]: IBM Integration Bus v9007 (PTCLBK01.ProvisionComptelService2New) [Thread 14140] (Msg
 5/6) BIP3152S: Socket error detected whilst invoking Web service located at host 10.254.166.242, port 44006, path /ilws/InstantLinkSOA.
May 12 00:57:36 iibapp1 user:err|error IIB[6095148]: IBM Integration Bus v9007 (PTCLBK01.ProvisionComptelService2New) [Thread 14140] (Msg
 6/6) BIP3150S: A socket error occurred. Operation: ::connect ::select(). Error Code: 79. Error Text: A remote host refused an attempted
connect operation..
May 12 00:57:54 iibapp1 user:err|error IIB[6095148]: IBM Integration Bus v9007 (PTCLBK01.ProvisionComptelService2New) [Thread 14140] (Msg
 1/6) BIP2232E: Error detected whilst handling a previous error in node 'com.ibm.pk.ptcl.esb.ComptelProv.Comptel_IL_Request_flow.Throw3'.
```

Comment: Worth adding multiple day logs, together with a sample output.

Comment: Edited with Log sample for 2 days. Please guide if possible for the solution :)

Comment: Almost all the comments addressed to you on your previous attempt at this question apply to this version, too.

Comment: @roaima There was no solution in the previous attempt that helped me though.

Comment: You didn't add any new information. Answer the comments as part of creating your question and it ceases to be a duplicate